# Does Truecalller app leak your phonebook?

Tags: contacts, privacy, truecaller

Sometimes, I cannot find new contacts that I add to the Truecaller phonebook, but sometimes, I think if it shares/leaks my contacts to the public. It shows other people's contact details that I never added there. So I am thinking if it is doing the same to me.

Android: 7.1.1
Phone: Oneplus 3T

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes** it does. When using the Truecaller application or services, you have already accepted their [privacy policy](https://www.truecaller.com/privacy-policy.html):

So, in this case, you agree that:

> Truecaller may use your personal information collected by their application to provide, maintain, improve, analyze and personalize their Services for other Users, partners and third party providers.
>
> More specifically, **Truecaller may use such information to provide names of contacts from your address book to other Trucaller users.**

Comment: Exactly. For details, see: [Truecaller is a privacy risk](http://www.ethow.com/2015/10/how-Truecaller-works-is-what-you-might-not-like.html). And if they say they use those data to "improve … their services for … partners and third party providers", that definitely smells for "selling your data". That's the way you pay for their service.

Comment: @Izzy Is there any alternative for TrueCaller that respects the user privacy?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 to be asked at our sister site. Or rather has been asked just a few hours before your question here: [Android app to to block international calls from a particular country](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/46435/185). See my answer there.

Answer (score 1):

Precisely. In fact, there is a plethora of evidence suggesting true caller is a privacy invader.

Just as [*Izzy* mentioned](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/184848/does-truecalller-app-leak-your-phonebook#comment237710_184850), it's clear that the phonebook databases are uploaded to their servers even without consent from the users whose data end up leaking into their servers.

Truecaller uses "crowd-sourcing" to get data to their servers. In [this article](http://mytechbuy.blogspot.co.ke/2017/09/how-true-caller-workscrowd-sourcing.html) by *Shaik Sharoz*, the author explains the logic behind crowd sourcing:

> The thing happens in this Crowd sourcing is they collect the data from you and shows to you in return. Suppose When a user installs the true caller app in his\her mobile, After installing it all the contacts which are present in the users mobile will sync with the servers of True caller app.

Consequently,

> This brings out a privacy issue that your name is appearing in the search results to others very openly without permission.