# Why no native support for phone call blocker by Regex +44.* in Oreo?

Tags: contacts, privacy, 8.0-oreo

There are many privacy problems in phone call blockers such as TrueCaller leaking your phonebook (thread [Does TrueCalller App leak your phonebook?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/184848/does-truecalller-app-leak-your-phonebook/184860#184860)) in Android phonebook blockers. 
I really think the support should be native.
I would like to understand why it is not at the moment.

There are many threads about the feature in non-native targets by 3rd party apps but none of those threads offer a simple, strong-security and strong-privacy approach for the problem: thread [Android app to to block international calls from a particular country](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/46435/63).

Example block function: block all UK phone numbers by Regex

- +44.* so matching UK country code and any other letter after it

OS: Android Oreo 8.0
Phone: Oneplus 3T

Comment: Natively?  Not that I know of.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Yes, exactly, therefore this thread.